# Rudin's RCA $5.22$ - An Abstract Approach to the Poisson Integral.

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, linear-transformations, banach-spaces, functional-inequalities

[image]

[image]

I  don’t understand how does the inequality $(3)$ shows that the mapping $f$ $\to$ $f(x)$ is a bounded linear functional on $M$, of norm 1 ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This is completely obvious. Ask yourself what $|g+ir|^2$ is **equal** to (by definition). Likewise, what is $|\alpha+i(\beta+r)|^2$ **equal** to? Therefore…

Comment: What is |$g+ir|^2$equal of by definition?

Comment: come on. What is the magnitude of a complex number?

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: I’ve edited the question. Please answer on this too and I’ll accept and upvote your answer

Comment: @JohnNash you need to review the definition of boundedness of a linear map.

Comment: I read it. But I still didn’t get it. Please give me some indications

Comment: @JohnNash I'm sorry, but this follows almost immediately from the definitions. Have you tried to verify it? Atleast show your attempt.

Comment: @peek-a-boo sorry for bumping into the comments. I am a little confused about how rudin proved positive definiteness of $\Lambda$. Doesn't $|\Lambda (f - 1)| \leq ||f - 1|| \leq  1$ imply that

Comment: @somitra start by asking yourself what is the definition of positive definiteness

Comment: @peek-a-boo $\Lambda f$ is non-negative for non-negative $f$. I think I'm assuming $\Lambda f$ to be real, which itself has to be proven.

Comment: @somitra yes, snd Rudin is proving exactly that in his last line (and the one after that). You still haven’t mentioned which part of Rudin’s argument is not clear.

Comment: @peek-a-boo It's all clear now. Thanks